# prove that the limit exists

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left(\dfrac{1}{(x^{2}-1)^{6}}\right)=\infty$$

Hey, can someone help me to prove this limit by the limit definition?

Comment: Given any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, choose $|x| <(\frac{1}{N}^\frac{1}{6} +1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, then?

Comment: @sqtrat:  This would provide (with a bit of additional argument) a sequence $x_n$ converging to $1$ (from above) such that the expression above grows without limit (i.e. tends to infinity).  However this doesn't completely address the limit above, both because it gives a one-sided sequential limit and also because it doesn't use the "limit definition" as I suspect the OP intends it.

Comment: What are your ideas, what have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any $M>0$. We will prove that there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-1|<\delta$ then

$$\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^6}>M.$$

(we can ommit $|\cdot|$, because this expression is nonnegative).Next we can write down the last expression as

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)^6(x+1)^6}.$$

Now choose

$$\delta=\min \left( 1,\frac{1}{4M^{1/6}} \right).$$

Now we have (by triangle inequality and $|x-1|<\delta$):

$$|x+1| \leq 2+|x-1| \leq 3,$$

so if $|x-1|<\delta$ :

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)^6(x+1)^6} \geq \frac{1}{3^6}\frac{1}{(x-1)^6} \geq \frac{1}{3^6} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{4M^{1/6}}\right)^6}=\frac{4^6}{3^6}M>M.$$